# How to avoid TCP/IP Fingerprinting

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I have the following setup:

```
 +-----------+   SSH Tunnels Over Socks5 Proxy    +--------------+
 |           |                                    |              |
 | Linux PC  +------------------------------------+ Proxy Server |
 |           |                                    |              |
 +-----------+                                    +--------------+
                                                          |
                                                          | SSH Tunnels
                                             +-------------------------+
                                             |                         |
                                             |                         |
                                       +-----------+             +-----------+
                                       |           |             |           |
                                       |   PI A    |             |   PI B    |
                                       |           |             |           |
                                       +-----------+             +-----------+
                                             |                          |
                                             |  WAN / Internet          |  WAN / Internet
                                             |                          |
                                             v                          v
```

First off: I'm not trying to defeat OS fingerprinting as discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/826960/how-to-defeat-nmaps-tcp-ip-fingerprinting-method-for-os-detection) or in other questions on SuperUser. I use Linux for the entire chain/stack and don't mind being identified as such.

**Background:**
I access the internet in another country due to censorship. I have two identical Raspberry PIs (Model 3B+, cloned SD card, only modified IP to work in their respective LANs) in two separate residential locations (different ISPs). I use them independently from one another and they serve as residential proxies to access the internet.

Traffic is routed through the PIs via SSH tunnels. These SSH tunnels are themselves tunneled through an encrypted Socks5 tunnel via a proxy server (it's the same for both PIs) to hide them from the local domestic censors/IP blocking.

This works so far.

**Problem:**
When I run tests on https://browserleaks.com/ip and https://doileak.com I get different results for "PI A" and "PI B".

For "PI A" I get MTU 1500 and connection type "ethernet or modem" while for "PI B" I get MTU 1440 and connection type "generic tunnel or VPN".

I want both of them to be identified as connection type "ethernet or modem" to hide the fact that they are proxies. Based on my research these tests seem to be using TCP/IP fingerprinting with p0f.

The interfaces of both PIs are set to MTU 1500, also iptables configs are identical. They have the same hardware, the SD card in "PI B" is basically a clone of "PI A". Both PIs are directly connected to their respective routers via ethernet. Also, for the Linux PC and Proxy server MTU is set to 1500 (which shouldn't make a difference though if I'm not mistaken).

Given the fact that the PIs are set-up identically, what am I missing?

PS: the title is probably not ideal but I'm not sure how to describe the problem in a few words

Comment: In PiB, what does this command show : `ifconfig | grep mtu`. [link](https://linuxhint.com/how-to-change-mtu-size-in-linux/)

Comment: This question seems to have two parts, and the first part to solve is "How do I diagnose the difference between A & B, so tunnel B isn't reducing path MTU due to 60 bytes of header overhead?" You require that the tunnel support tinygrams. Possibly you want to turn off the DF don't frag bit, and encourage IP packet reassembly at the tunnel egress.

Answer (score 0):

The MTU of 1500 configured in PI A & PI B is the default MTU for ethernet packets. This MTU is **only** between the first router (the internet router you own) and the PI.

The router the PI is connected to (router A) is connected to the next router (router B). Then router B is connected to another router (router C). And so on. This route ends at the destination (for example the server of browserleaks.com). This route depends on your geographical location and it is a little random. Also it changes over time.

The MTU between router A and router B is probably >= 1500 but this is not guaranteed. If it is smaller than 1500 then your packets are split as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723393/can-udp-packet-be-fragmented-to-several-smaller-ones). Also browserleaks.com will then display the smaller MTU.

Conclusion:

> browserleaks.com displays the maximum supported MTU **on the whole
> route** from the client to the server.

It is normal that you get different MTUs for PI A and PI B because they probably take different routes.

To verify they are using different routes you can run (on your Linux PC):

```
traceroute browserleaks.com
```

This lists all routers between you and the server (and also the server). Run it once for each PI.

Also note that on IPv6 packets cannot be split.